# Relays for long run time for science project

Tags: relay

I have a science project that requires a constant load of 12V 10 amperes. I have bought relays that flash on and off and all of them have stopped working.

One or two of the relays lasted three weeks, but I'd like to just buy one that can handle longer times without buying monthly.

I bought relays for cars that were rated 12V maximum 20 amperes.

Do you guys have any solutions for this issue?

Comment: Is there a datasheet that you can post of this relay?

Comment: What is the rate of switching the relays on and off? How many times per second? What exactly is the load that they are switching?

Comment: Hello. My last relay to last the longest is here https://www.amazon.co.uk/Flasher-Blinker-Motorcycle-Motorbike-Indicator/dp/B08QN57XR5?pd_rd_w=rV235&pf_rd_p=cf67f9c8-8798-4520-8d8a-5c22db6f393f&pf_rd_r=GDKZ1F1NAJ6SCXK6JX9Q&pd_rd_r=4055c778-39cd-4392-8168-f170e0f1ae2d&pd_rd_wg=Y49IO&pd_rd_i=B08QN57XR5&psc=1&ref_=pd_bap_m_rp_22_sc there is not much technical data available. My ohms is 1.4 on a very simple loop circuit.  I'm sorry I can't be more exact I'd need to be on my PC and I'm phone at the moment making it difficult to write out.

Comment: `project that requires a constant load` ... what is the function of the relay? ... if the load is switched off, then it is not a constant load

Answer (score 8):

A relay designed for automotive applications may only have a life of perhaps 50,000 operations at full current with a benign (eg. resistive) load. An inductive, capacitive, tungsten or motor load could be much worse.

In three weeks there are 3 * 168 * 3600 = 1.8 million seconds, so if the relay cycles every 30 or 40 seconds it could wear out in 3 weeks.

There are longer life relays, but perhaps your application would be best suited by some kind of solid-state relay (SSR) or a MOSFET, which would ideally last indefinitely.

The details depend heavily on the exact nature of the load.

Comment: Hello. I will buy this relay. https://www.amazon.co.uk/NOFUEL-Module-Single-SSR-40DA-24-480VAC/dp/B09C7J8RKF/ref=mp_s_a_1_7_sspa?crid=3VCV2NEJ43T6I&keywords=solid+state+relay&qid=1647333272&sprefix=solid+state+relay+%2Caps%2C129&sr=8-7-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFKM1hDRlAwSjBQV0YmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTAyMTY5OTkxU00xQ1RGU0tPRjNaJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA1MDIxNzlHU0lEOUtDMFJZVjUmd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9waG9uZV9zZWFyY2hfbXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ== will I need a heat sink for 12v 10amps running for one hour and 30 minutes? Thank you.

Comment: @Flea - Hi, I'm not answering for *Spehro* but I saw your comment and I wanted to warn you that buying components from Amazon, eBay, AliExpress has risks, as some sellers on those sites are known to supply counterfeit components. See examples [here](https://protosupplies.com/inferior-counterfeit-fotek-ssr-25-solid-state-relays-on-the-market/), [here](https://www.ul.com/node/81246) & [here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/warning-dont-buy-fotek-solid-state-relays/). Even if your seller seems to be selling different SSRs to those examples, that doesn't mean they are genuine. Caveat emptor.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to wire this solid state relay up so my EMP pulses on and off just like it did with the mechanical car flasher? My circuit is one wire that loops - that needs to flash on and off - flahs speed not so important just as long as it does that continually.

Comment: I purchased the MGR 40 https://www.amazon.co.uk/NOFUEL-Module-Single-SSR-40DA-24-480VAC/dp/B09C7J8RKF/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?crid=1285ZFNWF28QJ&keywords=solid%2Bstate%2Brelay&qid=1647534628&sprefix=%2Caps%2C84&sr=8-3-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExSldDSzdGUEJTRzY5JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMTk4ODA1WVBYQ1VBR1pZRTg5JmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAxMjA5Mzc0TzhSSDhCOEJCNkImd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGYmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl&th=1

Comment: That kind of relay only works with AC. With DC it will switch on but never switch off. Also it won't properly switch 12VAC, minimum 24VAC.

Comment: I see what type would I need? im only running 12v 10 amps. Really need some help here as im not that bright with electronics.

Comment: My last sentence was intended as a hint to supply a LOT more information. As this question has been closed perhaps you should open another  related to this, but please try to provide all the information up front.